# Return variable for input fields in JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some code.

```
$('#my-mkfile').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //window.console.log('mkdir button pressed');
    f[0].elfinder.ui.exec('mkfile');
    $('#finder .el-finder-cwd').find(':text').val('XXXXXX');
    $(document.body).click();
    var timestamp=0;
}
```

At the moment it works with a button. And creates a val named 'XXXXXX'

```
<input type="button" value="my mkfile" id="my-mkfile">
```

How can I change it so that it is a text field and passes to `val('XXXXXX')`. I just spent a day on it lol. Should be easy.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry if its not clear. I will try to explain. I need a textfield in a form that can take the user input and pass it as a variable. I am not sure if I can do this without ajax.

Comment: Whereto do you want to pass it? Maybe you want to create a new <input type="text" id="someId" value="" /> then set its value to 'XXXX' $("#someId").val('XXXX'); then you can always fetch that value by .val(); on the input text field element.

Comment: Thanks for reply Antonio. The value is set to XXXXX for my example, and this is the value that is being sent. SO when I press a button it creates a file on elfinder file manager called XXXXX. How could I make it so it takes the user input instead of using XXXXX. many thanks.

Comment: @Simon... All you have to do is remove the line that sets the value: `$('#finder .el-finder-cwd').find(':text').val('XXXXXX');`

Comment: Hi Box 9. I tried that. Still no joy. I am struggling a bit with this one. It seems so simple. Should I create a form and submit it via Ajax. A submit button will always reload the page. Is there a alternative.

Comment: @Simon, if you want to send data to a server without reloading the page then yes you have to make an asynchronous call, which you can do with jquery, see the .load .get .ajax functions. You dont need a form, you just 'read' the value of the element/field you want, and call .ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Add a text field

```
<input type="text" id="textFieldID" value="" />
```

and change the code to

```
$('#finder .el-finder-cwd').find(':text').val($('#textFieldID').val());
```

Comment: BRILLANT.THANKS. I spent all day on this. Much appreciated amit. I owe you.

Comment: @Simon why don't you flag this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry just one further thing. I wish to pass the same variable to an ajax function.   $.get("ajax.php",{'action':'new','text':'XXXXXXXX.','rand':Math.random()},function(msg){
XXXXXX is where I need to pass the val($('#textFieldID' variable. Also Is there a tool for checking javascript syntax. I am quite new but my main problem is syntax errors.

Comment: @Simon, $.get("ajax.php",{'action':'new','text':$('#finder .el-finder-cwd').find(':text').val($('#textFieldID').val()),'rand':Math.random()},function(msg){ ... You should look into using an IDE, or a very good editor such as vim. If your serverside is Java then lookinto Eclipse or Netbeans. If its python try pycharm, if its php try vim, or somethiing like Notepad++. If you want more, Intellij I think has even better inspections.

Comment: Sorry, should have been, $('#textFieldID').val() this will give you the value of the textField input element and you can place it anywhere you like where you need that value, even computations or ajax.